# Galeria de Imagens dinamicas ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, imagem

Eu tenho o seguinte Codigo,
 Ele carrega a fotos nesse placeholder. ID="phFotos">

```
 public partial class ImovelDetalhe : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private ImovelBo _imovelBo;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                carregarInformacoes();
            }
        }

        private void carregarInformacoes()
        {
            int codigoImovel = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CodImovel"], out codigoImovel);

            _imovelBo = new ImovelBo();
            var imovel = _imovelBo.ObterDetalhe(codigoImovel);

            if (imovel != null)
            {
                lblDescricao.Text = imovel.Descricao;
                lblOperacao.Text = imovel.Operacao;
                lblCidade.Text = imovel.Cidade;
                lblLocalizacao.Text = imovel.Localizacao;
                lblTipoImovel.Text = imovel.Tipo;
                lblQtDormitorios.Text = imovel.QntDormitorio.ToString();
                lblValor.Text = imovel.Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");

                if (imovel.Fotos != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in imovel.Fotos)
                    {
                        Image foto = new Image();
                        foto.Width = 500;
                        foto.Height = 400;
                        foto.ImageUrl = item;
                        phFotos.Controls.Add(foto);
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    }
```

E quando executo as imagens aparece assim : uma em baixo da outra  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sera que alguem poderia nos ajudar a fazer um carrosel, slide show ou um banner ?
conforme esse exemplo ou mais simples :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu nao consegui passar o caminho das fotos que estao no banco e na raiz

Comment: Como é seu controle no aspx ?

Comment: <div class="photo">
se e o controle das fotos ? se sim e esse aqui 
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phFotos"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            
        </div>

Comment: Não seria melhor criar algum serviço chamando a lista das imagens (asmx ou ashx) e fazer uma chamada ajax utilizando algum componente de imagem em JS?

Comment: O que está faltando é utilizar alguma lib JS para administrar a exibição das imagens em formato de carrosel/slider/galeria, como por exemplo esse aqui: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Carousel-Image-Gallery-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery-jCarousel-Plugin.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pega essa lista que você tem com as fotos (imovel.Fotos), atribui para um controle Repeater do ASP.NET e o javascript $('#mycarousel').jcarousel(); irá se encarregar de exibir da forma correta.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
   });
 </script>
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <img alt="" style='height: 75px; width: 75px' src='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Ao colocar o id do **ul** mycarousel e transforma-lo em um jcarousel, toda tag **li** que estiver com a propriedade src correta será exibida no seu slider.

A lib JS é essa aqui: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/